# indication function within an integral

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

I've got show that 
$f(x.y)= \frac{\alpha^2}{x}y^{-\alpha-1} \mathbb{1}_{1\leq x\leq y}$ (where  $\alpha >0$) is a density function. The function $\mathbb{1}$ is the indication function. I know that this integral must be one. But I'm getting false results. I'm not sure if my attempt with $\int_x^\infty[\int_1^y \! \frac{\alpha^2}{x}y^{-\alpha-1}\, \mathrm{d}x ]\mathrm{d}y$ is correct with  the conditions of the indiacation function. Am I false?

Answer (score 1):

You integral is wrong . 
You should have either $x$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$ , and $y$ from $x$ to $\infty$,

or $y$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$ , and $x$ from $1$ to $y$.

You want to know $$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}{f(x,y)dxdy}=\alpha^2\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{x}\int_{x}^{\infty}{y^{-(\alpha+1)}}dy}$$.

We have that 
$$\int_{x}^{\infty}{y^{-(\alpha+1)}}dy=\frac{x^{-\alpha}}{\alpha}$$

By substituing the above result to your integral, we have  ,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}{f(x,y)dxdy}=\alpha\int_{1}^{\infty}{x^{-(\alpha+1)}}dx=1$$